# backgroud-size with background-position in css sprite image

Tags: css

I have three (3) social icons in one image and same icons with double size for retina display in another image. I thought my CSS would be like this:

```css
.social-media li a {
    width: 44px;
    height: 48px;
    background: url('social-media.png') no-repeat;
} 

@media (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-resolution: 120dpi), (min-resolution: 1.25dppx) { 
    .social-media li a {
        background: url('social-media@2x.png') no-repeat;
        background-size: 44px 48px;  /* same with width & height of normal (non-retina) image for fitting in equal space */
    }
}
```

But, it seems that `background-size` creates issue here. But, without that property, I can't fit retina display's image in `44 x 48` (normal image's block) dimensional block. What's the proper way?

In my fiddle below, you'll see, I have put three block. 1<sup>st</sup> one is for normal image, 2<sup>nd</sup> one is for displaying retina's image demo with their original double size (it's basically to examine correctness of my `background-position`), and last one is for displaying retina's image demo within normal image's size block (as I like to check that at first at normal device instead of retina device to see how they will behave in retina device).

In short, I need my last block's result correctly.

[Fiddle Demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/wqkewd03/1/)

```css
#normal .social-media {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
#normal .social-media li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#normal .social-media li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#normal .social-media li a {
  width: 44px;
  height: 48px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/xr8VaHh.png') no-repeat;
  display: block;
}
#normal .social-media li a.facebook-icon {
  background-position: 0 -60px;
}
#normal .social-media li a.facebook-icon:hover {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
#normal .social-media li a.twitter-icon {
  background-position: -64px -60px;
}
#normal .social-media li a.twitter-icon:hover {
  background-position: -64px 0;
}
#normal .social-media li a.linked-in-icon {
  background-position: -128px -60px;
}
#normal .social-media li a.linked-in-icon:hover {
  background-position: -128px 0;
}
/***************** For Retina background image with original size **************/

#forRetinaOriginalSize .social-media {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
#forRetinaOriginalSize .social-media li a {
  width: 88px;
  height: 96px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Cif180D.png') no-repeat;
  display: block;
}
#forRetinaOriginalSize .social-media li a.facebook-icon {
  background-position: -30px -141px;
}
#forRetinaOriginalSize .social-media li a.twitter-icon {
  background-position: -157px -141px;
}
#forRetinaOriginalSize .social-media li a.linked-in-icon {
  background-position: -285px -141px;
}
#forRetinaOriginalSize .social-media li a.facebook-icon:hover {
  background-position: -30px -21px;
}
#forRetinaOriginalSize .social-media li a.twitter-icon:hover {
  background-position: -157px -21px;
}
#forRetinaOriginalSize .social-media li a.linked-in-icon:hover {
  background-position: -285px -21px;
}
/***************** For Retina background image with normal size **************/

#forRetinaNormalSize .social-media {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
#forRetinaNormalSize .social-media li a {
  width: 44px;
  height: 48px;
  display: block;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Cif180D.png') no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 44px 48px;
  background-size: 44px 48px;
}
#forRetinaNormalSize .social-media li a.facebook-icon {
  background-position: -30px -141px;
}
#forRetinaNormalSize .social-media li a.twitter-icon {
  background-position: -157px -141px;
}
#forRetinaNormalSize .social-media li a.linked-in-icon {
  background-position: -285px -141px;
}
#forRetinaNormalSize .social-media li a.facebook-icon:hover {
  background-position: -30px -21px;
}
#forRetinaNormalSize .social-media li a.twitter-icon:hover {
  background-position: -157px -21px;
}
#forRetinaNormalSize .social-media li a.linked-in-icon:hover {
  background-position: -285px -21px;
}
/* HiDPI support for Normal */

@media (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
(min-resolution: 120dpi),
(min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {
  #normal .social-media li a {
    background: image-url('http://i.imgur.com/Cif180D.png') no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 44px 48px;
    background-size: 44px 48px;
  }
  #normal .social-media li a.facebook-icon {
    background-position: -30px -141px;
  }
  #normal .social-media li a.twitter-icon {
    background-position: -157px -141px;
  }
  #normal .social-media li a.linked-in-icon {
    background-position: -285px -141px;
  }
  #normal .social-media li a.facebook-icon:hover {
    background-position: -30px -21px;
  }
  #normal .social-media li a.twitter-icon:hover {
    background-position: -157px -21px;
  }
  #normal .social-media li a.linked-in-icon:hover {
    background-position: -285px -21px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="normal">
      <h3>1. Normal Background Image</h3>
      <ul class="social-media clearfix">
        <li>
          <a class="facebook-icon" href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="twitter-icon" href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="linked-in-icon" href="#"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12" id="forRetinaOriginalSize">
      <h3>2. For Retina Background Image (with Original size of itself)</h3>
      <ul class="social-media clearfix">
        <li>
          <a class="facebook-icon" href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="twitter-icon" href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="linked-in-icon" href="#"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12" id="forRetinaNormalSize">
      <h3>3. For Retina Background Image (with Normal or compressed size)</h3>
      <ul class="social-media clearfix">
        <li>
          <a class="facebook-icon" href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="twitter-icon" href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="linked-in-icon" href="#"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course it makes no sense to resize the _whole_ 536*258 pixel sized image to the icon dimensions of 44*48 pixels …you’ll want to modify only _one_ dimension, and let the other adapt automatically.

Comment: Got it. But, I tried with like this too:  #normal .social-media li a.facebook-icon {background-size: 44px 48px;} which was not working too.

Comment: @CBroe - you won't resize it to 44x48, just one part of it need to have that dimension. This is essence of sprites - use one large image and show required parts where you want it. So for 40 images you can have 1 file, and 39 less http requests.

Comment: @Przemysław yes, I know how sprites work. But resizing the _complete_ sprite image to 44*48 is what the OP tried, and that of course makes no sense.

Comment: @CBroe I must misunderstood you. You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to divide all sizes by 2 using images for high-denisity device (@2x), for this you need even sized image (as all sizes will be divided by 2) to look good.

I've modified facebook icon for example: https://jsfiddle.net/wqkewd03/3/

```
#forRetinaNormalSize .social-media li a {
  width: 44px;
  height: 48px;
  display: block;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Cif180D.png') no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 268px 129px;
  background-size: 268px 129px;

#forRetinaNormalSize .social-media li a.facebook-icon {
  background-position: -15px -70px;
}

#forRetinaNormalSize .social-media li a.facebook-icon:hover {
  background-position: -15px -10px;
}
```

I usually use "@2x" as default (for that kind of images: icons, etc.) with this method, images are not too much larger, scaling is not bad with todays browsers so why not to use 1 version and half of code you need to target it specifically. And it seems to be future-proof when high density desktop screens arrive.

Comment: ok, so positioning need to be divided by 2 too! 
I will remember your advice about using only one version image. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The age of image icons is over. You should switch to using a glyph icon library. They are cleaner and, since they are a font/vector, scale to almost any size.

By combining this [CSS Hexagon tutorial](https://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html) with [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) I have created an alternative which does not rely on sprites or aliasing of images.

If you are using SASS or SCSS, this CSS below can be reduced even more.

```css
.social-media:before, .social-media:after {
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 52px solid transparent;
  border-right: 52px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.social-media:before {
  top: -30px;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #6C6;
}
.social-media {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 104px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #6C6;
  position: relative;
}
.social-media:after {
  bottom: -30px;
  border-top: 30px solid #6C6;
}

.social-media span {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}

.social-media:before { border-bottom: 30px solid #000000; }
.social-media { background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; }
.social-media:after { border-top: 30px solid #000000; }

.social-media.facebook:hover:before { border-bottom: 30px solid #0268A0; }
.social-media.facebook:hover { background-color: #0268A0; color: #FFFFFF; }
.social-media.facebook:hover:after { border-top: 30px solid #0268A0; }

.social-media.twitter:hover:before { border-bottom: 30px solid #03BEE4; }
.social-media.twitter:hover { background-color: #03BEE4; color: #FFFFFF; }
.social-media.twitter:hover:after { border-top: 30px solid #03BEE4; }

.social-media.linkedin:hover:before { border-bottom: 30px solid #0098DC; }
.social-media.linkedin:hover { background-color: #0098DC; color: #FFFFFF; }
.social-media.linkedin:hover:after { border-top: 30px solid #0098DC; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="social-media facebook">
  <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
</div>

<div class="social-media twitter">
  <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>
</div>

<div class="social-media linkedin">
  <span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span>
</div>
```

---

## SCSS Rule

```scss
@mixin hex($bgcolor:#000000, $fgcolor:#FFFFFF) {
  &:before { border-bottom: 30px solid $bgcolor; };
  background-color: $bgcolor; color: $fgcolor;
  &:after { border-top: 30px solid $bgcolor; };
}

.social-media { @include hex(); }
.social-media.facebook:hover { @include hex(#0268A0); }
.social-media.twitter:hover { @include hex(#03BEE4); }
.social-media.linkedin:hover { @include hex(#0098DC); }
```